# Mapbox-gl-js gives typeerror: 't' is undefined with tiles

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles

Link to problem: https://khuts.org/webmap/osm-bright-style/mines.html
Neither the mapbox-street layer nor the tile layer show. 
This map has an mbtiles file served using tileserver-php.  The error refers to tile-coord.js, which does not seem to have any property 't' in it.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you extend on your question? How are you creating the layer causing the problem?

Comment: The relevant code is                map.on('style.load', function() {
   map.addSource("operating", {
       "type": "vector",
       "data": "http://khuts.org/webmap/tileserver-php/operations.mbtiles"
   });

   map.addLayer({
     "id": "operating", 
     "type": "circle", 
     "source": "operating", 
     "paint": {
         "circle-radius": 10,
         "circle-color": "#ccc"
     }
   });

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515944/mapbox-gl-js-gives-typeerror-t-is-undefined-with-tiles?noredirect=1#comment84059059_48515944) here, you need to change how you create your data source. `vector` sources don't accept a `data` option, you either need to supply `tiles` (an array of tile urls) or an `url` (an url pointing to a [TileJSON](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-tilejson/) file):

```
map.addSource('my-source', {
  type: 'vector',
  // either "tiles"
  tiles: ['http://my-tile-server/{z}/{x}/{y}'],
  // or "url"
  url: 'http://my-tile-server/tiles.json'
});
```

If you are using `tileserver-php`, it supports both:
- tile urls (z/x/y)
- tile jsons

See its documentation of "Supported Protocols": https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php#supported-protocols

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot install node / npm on a hosted, shared server, which is why tileserver-php was the choice. I will have to extract the tiles from the archive and serve them that way. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I updated my answer. tileserver-php also exposes tile urls and tile.json.